# Install wordpress in another wordpress's subdirectory

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site setup at the root directory for example: [www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com](http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com) and now I would like to install another wordpress at one of the subdirectory of it: [www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/folder/](http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/folder/)

After the installation, I cannot access the wordpress' admin page at the subdirectory, it redirects me to the root wordpress' 404 page "Oops! That page can’t be found."

How can I achieve to have 2 wordpress install and one of them is at the subdirectory of the other?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you need to edit the .htaccess file in your subdirectory WordPress install.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /folder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
  
# END WordPress
```